# How to create new list by adding existing lists using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator

I would like to join word from one nested list together with the word "and" in between. For example:

l1 = [Patrick, Peter, Jerome], [Lisa, Karen, Alice]

l2 should be: [Patrick and Lisa, Peter and Karen, Jerome and Alice]

The code should not make a difference whether there are 2,3 or whatever amount of lists in the nested list.

I have tried iterating over the range of lists in the variable and then append the result to a new variable. However, the outcome is just the first combination or the results end after the second combination.

```py
def names(one):
    newlist = []
    x = 0
    for y in range(len(one)):
        newlist.append(one[x][y] + " and " + one[x+1][y])
        x += 1
        return newlist
```

['Patrick and Lisa']

is what i got untill now. I know it has something to do with the iteration but since i am pretty new to python i got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `l1` is a tuple of two elements. Use the following:

```py
l2 = []

for name_a, name_b in zip(l1[0], l1[1]):
    l2.append(name_a + ' and ' + name_b)
```

If you are using Python 3.6+ you can use an f-string:

```py
l2 = []

for name_a, name_b in zip(l1[0], l1[1]):
    l2.append(f'{name_a} and {name_b}')
```

Also keep in mind that you can also use a list-comprehension.

**Python 3.6+**

```py
l2 = [f'{name_a} and {name_b}' for name_a, name_b in zip(l1[0], l1[1])]
```

```py
l2 = [name_a + ' and ' + name_b for name_a, name_b in zip(l1[0], l1[1])]
```

**Note:** If you are not allowed to use `zip` use `range` and use index notation as follows:

```py
l2 = []

for i in range(len(l1[0])):
    name_a = l1[0][i]
    name_b = l1[1][i]
    l2.append(name_a + ' and ' + name_b)
```

**Update:** based on the previous comments, you should use the following:

```py
l2 = []

for i in range(len(l1[0])):
    l2.append(' and '.join(e[i] for e in l1))
```

Comment: Since this is an exercise i am limited to using for loops and indices, unfortunatly i can't make use of zip

Comment: This answer helps me a lot but leaves 1 problem. If i now have more than 2 lists in my nested list, it wont take the ones after position [1] into account. Can you help me with that problem?

Comment: @Koenwijnen, can you provide an example of that input and the example of the expected output?

Comment: Yes I can. Lets say the input nested list = [Banana, Apple, Pear], [Elephant, Monkey, Snail], [Blue, Red, Yellow]. In your example the third lists won't be taken into account. However i need my code to access all lists in the nested lists regardless of how many those are. So the expected outcome would be: [Banana and Elephant and Snail, etc..]

Comment: @KoenWijnen, what is your expected output in that case?

Comment: I pressed enter too early, see above for my expected output

Comment: Yes! It is the answer i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KoenWijnen, I would appreciate if you upvote/validate this answer? Thanks too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to get a combination of names from sub lists and the list having "and" repeated the number of times elements are present in the first list `one[0]` :

```
one = [['Patrick', 'Peter', 'Jerome'], ['Lisa', 'Karen', 'Alice']]
name_tup = zip(one[0], ["and"] * len(one[0]), one[1])
```

Then use a list comprehension to generate the out list from the tuple returned by `zip`. Using unpacking the three elements are joined by a whitespace in between using the `join` function:

```
list = [ " ".join([x, y, z]) for x, y, z in name_tup]

>>> list
['Patrick and Lisa', 'Peter and Karen', 'Jerome and Alice']
```